# Creating an alias for emacs in read-only mode on Linux in my .tcshrc file

Tags: linux, emacs, command-line

Just so you know this is my first ever post.

Basically, I am trying to put in an alias (or something) in my .tcshrc file so that I can open a file in emacs read-only (without having to type the blurb below everytime). I found this - https://superuser.com/questions/204236/how-can-i-open-a-file-read-only-from-command-line-with-emacs-vi-vim - but since tcsh does not support functions (I think) I cannot use this method.

The command line text for opening emacs in read-only format is this:

emacs *FILE_NAME* --eval '(setq buffer-read-only t)'

Any ideas?

Thanks
P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes and parens in tcsh aliases can be problematic, so `--funcall toggle-read-only` in Satish's answer is probably easier to use than `--eval`. To insert an argument after the filename, you can use the `\!:1` expression for the first argument:

```
alias emacs-ro emacs \!:1 --funcall toggle-read-only
```

Comment: ...except if you use it to open a read-only file, in which case the buffer will be toggled to writeable. Explicitly setting the buffer to read-only is a much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would create script called `emacs-ro` and place in your PATH

```
#!/bin/bash
emacs "$@" --funcall toggle-read-only
```

Or you can use your options too.

```
--eval '(setq buffer-read-only t)'
```

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks. Using the funcall instead of eval solved it!

Answer (score 0):

As per Satish's answer, but with the suggestion that if you're using Emacs >=24.3 you can and should use `read-only-mode` instead of `toggle-read-only`, The latter will still 'work' but is now obsoleted.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
emacs "$@" --funcall read-only-mode
```